# Getting spot gold price without API

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

Apparently it was possible to query spot gold data using Pandas Datareader, but when I run the query mentioned in the [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/842), I get an error.  Alternative methods welcome.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data
import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override()

data.DataReader("GOLDAMGBD228NLBM", data_source="fred", start="2022-06-01")
```

> - GOLDAMGBD228NLBM: No data found for this date range, symbol may be delisted

Comment: yahoofinance module uses API calls to fetch your data. Datareader creates dataframes for the source data fetched from yahoo finance. To avoid your error, try this date format - `start='20220601'`.

Comment: That's not the issue - try what you proposed and you get the same error.  The format I specified does work with other symbols (e.g. '^GSPC')

Comment: Its probably been taken down. Ref link: https://news.research.stlouisfed.org/2022/01/ice-benchmark-administration-ltd-iba-data-to-be-removed-from-fred/